# JQuery AJAX HTML Find Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've read similar Q/A on SO but this simple piece of JQuery AJAX code is still driving me nuts --

```
$.get($('#pager a').attr('href'), function(data) {
    var data = $(data).wrap("<div />");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.find('.content'));
    console.log(data.find('#next_page'));
}, "html");
```

The HTML returned by the AJAX call is --

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">lorum</div>
    <div class="content">ipsum</div>
    <div id="next_page">
      <a href="/page/2"></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the console logs --

```
[<TextNode textContent="\n\n \n \n ">, div.content, <TextNode textContent="\n ">, div.content, <TextNode textContent="\n ">, div#next_page, <TextNode textContent="\n \n">]
[ ]
[ ]
```

I can't for my life figure out why data.find('.content') and data.find('#next_page') match nothing.

Any pointer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: propably because your data is not interpreted as an html file ? the console log displays '\n' multiple times, which is odd because you would have to add it manually via <br/> in your html code, what your not doing.

Comment: the extra carriage returns are added by the templating system and not really relevant to this question. I just chose to show the console logs verbatim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`.wrap()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) documentation:

> This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

The set of elements in this case are all the child nodes of `body`. `.find()` will search for descendants of these nodes, but not the nodes itself.

Either use [`.filter()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead or create an empty `div` and set `data` as its content:

```
var data = $('<div />').html(data);
```