# jQuery find not working on AJAX function

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm trying to set up a relatively simple AJAX pagination with jQuery like this:

```
$('.pagination a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type    : 'GET',
            url     : $('.pagination a').attr('href'),
            success : function(html) {
                // Get older pager
                var oldPager = $(html).find('.pagination a'); // Not working
            }
        });
});
```

For some reason I can't get the next page's pagination link even though it does exists, if I `console.log($(html))` I do get all the existing elements including the `.pagination` div with the `a` tag, not sure with the `find` method returns nothing. I've done it like this in the past and I don't remember having this much trouble.

Here's the `html` string to help with debugging: http://pastebin.com/dD8GnG78 it's basically the next page's html. I also tried to `console.log($(html).find('div'))` just for testing and noticed that not all `divs` are getting returned for some reason.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, replace `$('.pagination a').on('click', function(e) {` with `$('.pagination').on('click', 'a', function(e) {` - event delegation performs better.

Comment: Also, you probably want this `url: this.href,`

Comment: Thanks for the performance tips, sadly still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you are actually trying to do, I think the issue lies with your jQuery selectors:

url     : `$('.pagination a').attr('href')`

Should be:

url     : `$(e.target).attr('href')`

And, what is your variable "oldPager" meant to contain? The way you have it now, it will contain ALL the pagination anchors from the HTML you just requested with the AJAX call.

**EDIT:**

Ok, try this:

```
var oldPager = $(html).filter('.pagination').find('a');
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, sadly still doesn't work, the `html` variable is meant to contain the pagination element of the next page so I can fetch the `href` attr and update the ajax link.

Comment: How are your pagination links created? Do you really need to do an AJAX GET request on an entire page to retrieve it?

Comment: Well it's a wordpress blog so I'm using the `next_posts_link()` function to render a link to the next page, it actually works for the first click but since I'm not able to update the `href` attr then just the 2nd page posts are getting added.

Comment: Just fiddled around a bit, and think I found the solution. Edited my above answer for you.

Comment: Great thanks, do you mind telling me why it works with `filter` and not with the regular `find`?

Comment: Found this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790954/jquery-ajax-html-find-not-working

And then did some testing.

Apparently .find() only searches the children of the selected elements, not the elements themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are finding the object.

Are you looking for href attribute of it?

`$(html).find('.pagination a').attr("href");`

or the markup/text inside the anchor tag ?

`$(html).find('.pagination a').html();`  .. or `.text();`

Comment: I'm looking for the href attr but if `$(html).find('.pagination a')` returns nothing so I can't get it

Comment: gotya, how are you checking the return of $(html).find('.pagination a') ?

Comment: I tried `console.log($(html).find('.pagination a'))` but it returns an empty object

Comment: hmmm, not used it this way , what about using .filter instead of the .find ( it might be that .find only works on an living DOM ) .. not tried it.

Comment: + can always fall back to good old substring *if your ajax return is small

Comment: in addition, run a test to find or filter something  like this - .find('.pagination').find(a).attr('href') -  instead of .find('.pagination a') - lets eliminate that extra step.